# How can I make my toggle menu close when I click away?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm am struggling to get the drop down to close when I click away.

It only closes when I click the the parent.

```
$("#nav > ul > li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mRwb/3/

What's the best solution in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you'd do that

```
$('#nav > ul > li').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('a', this).addClass('hover');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if (! $(this).hasClass('active') )
            $('a', this).removeClass('hover');
    },
    click: function(){
        $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.hover').not( $(this).find('a') ).removeClass('hover');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('#nav .active').length === 0 )
        $('.active').removeClass('active').find('a').removeClass('hover');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2mRwb/18/)

Fixed a few other issues as well

Answer (score 1):

Add this following event handler

```
$("#nav > ul > li > ul").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/2mRwb/4/)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm try to get the menu to close when I click away not on mouse leave. Basically the same as the bootstrap drop down or stack overflow.

Comment: ok so clicking on rest of the body will disappear the menu rught?

Comment: Exactly. And I only want one to be open at a time. Sorry if im asking to much

Answer (score 0):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mRwb/7/)

Check jQuery **[mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)** / **[mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)** event.

```
$("#nav > ul > li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('mouseup',function(e){

    $('li.active').removeClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I always say the simplest way is the best. I definitely want to start getting into jquery more. Very fun library to work with.